# How to send an Apollo Request (graphql) with queries?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have such task so send a query with these params

```
 {operationName:getPostList,variables:{input:{type:post,locale:en,projectId:1}},query:query getPostList($input: PostSearchType) {\n  posts(input: $input, paging: {limit: 12}) {\n    items {\n      id\n    type\n   locale\n  shortDescription\n fullUrl\n   thumbnail\n   tags\n      title\n      publishedAt\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
```

However i don't understand how to specify those parameters in gql function (apollo-boost)
This is my request

```
const GET_MOVIES = gql`
{
    query getPostList($input: PostSearchType){
        posts(
            input:$input,
            paging : {
                limit:12
            }
            items{
                id,
                type,
                locale,
                shortDescription,
                fullUrl,
                thumbnail,
                tags,
                title,
                publishedAt,
                __typename
            }
            __typename
        )
    }
    "operationName":"getPostList",
    "variables":{
        "input":{
            "type":"post",
             "locale":"en",
             "projectId":1  
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Did you read this documentation? I hope this will help - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/

Comment: Yes i've read the documentation and i am sending requests exactly how documentation says, however i am constantly getting GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "1".

Comment: Can you add piece of code here so that I can see it how exactly you are doing it?

Comment: @AbhishekRaj, i've added my code. It throws an syntax error

Comment: gql is for query only, other things are part of requesting, search for axios or fetch examples/answers (mutations with variables) ... or better tutorial

Comment: i've already done this task with axios but i've been said to rewrite it with apollo..

Comment: then use usqQuery, follow docs, too

Comment: Yes @lev, Xadm is right. If you are confused with docs, I'll give a sample code example to you. But documentation is itself very good and self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into sample code. You can adjust it as per your requirement.

```
/**
 * Sample code to showcase how queries work in React Apollo client
 */

import React from "react";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const GET_MOVIES = gql`
  query getPostList($input: PostSearchType) {
    posts(input: $input) {
      id
      type
      locale
      shortDescription
      fullUrl
      thumbnail
      tags
      title
      publishedAt
      __typename
    }
  }
`;

const ApolloReactExample = () => {
  const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_MOVIES, {
    variables: { input: "YOUR_INPUT" },
  });

  return <div></div>;
};

export default ApolloReactExample;
```